# Problem using the word "RSS" as a tag

Tags: tags, redirect, rss, feed

I'm using RSS as a tag for some of my blog posts, and I was using them without any problem.

```
myblog.com/tag/rss/
```

But I've just realised that Google Webmaster Tools gives me some related errors.

The issue is this: when trying to retrieve the feed of this tag, from

```
myblog.com/tag/rss/feed/
```

it gets redirected to

```
myblog.com/tag/feed/
```

And this gives an error.

Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do yet due to [a bug in Wordpress core](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21700).

A workaround was provided in Wordpress ticket

```
function disable_canonical_redirection_for_tag_feeds() {
if ( is_feed() && is_tag() )
    remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'disable_canonical_redirection_for_tag_feeds' );
```